# Update QML Window property flags from C++

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a basic qml application QWindow that already defines the property `flags`. I would like to change/update the property `flags` from `main.cpp` so that it is not frameless. I know I can do it directly in QML but I'd like to change it dynamically without re-compiling. I have found a number of examples but none show how to do this after using `QQmlApplicationEngine::load()` method. I posted my code below and I am able to see the current flags decimal value `2048` or hex value `0x800`. According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) the hex value of `0x800` refers to `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` which is the current setting. I have tried to modify the `flags` property but the window doesn't update.

```
// Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  id: window
  objectName: "window"
  ...
  flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

  ...
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::quit, &app,
                     &QGuiApplication::quit);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(
                &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
                [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl) QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        QVariant obj2 = obj->property("flags");
        if (obj2.isValid()) {
            Qt::WindowFlags flags = qvariant_cast<Qt::WindowFlags>(obj2);
            flags &= ~Qt::FramelessWindowHint;
            auto *tmp = dynamic_cast<QWindow*>(obj);
            tmp->setFlags(flags);
            tmp->show();
        }
    },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me. I'm on Qt 5.15.0 on Linux.

Comment: why did you create obj2? you can easily setProperty from c++.

Comment: @JarMan Hmm. I'm on Qt 5.15.2 MSVC 2019 64 bit. It definitely doesn't work. I even have tried `obj->setProperty("flags", 0);` to just zero out the flag but doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I have to use `obj->setProperty("flags", Qt::Window);` when I want to override the `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have obj and if you want that main.qml change you can easily add property to this:

`obj->setProperty("flags", Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QWindow>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication        app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine  engine;
    const QUrl             url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl)
    {
        if (!obj && (url == objUrl))
        {
          QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }

        obj->setProperty("flags", Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

**Edited :**

[image]

Comment: The flag in qml `Window` is set with `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` I would like to override that in the connect lambda like you are showing but with `obj->setProperty("flags", 0);` but it doesn't seem to work with Qt 5.15.2 MSVC 2019 64bit.

Comment: It works for me , I use Qt 5.14.0 in ubuntu , First, try it with MinGW  .@slayer

Comment: @slayer , I edited and show you my screen and codes that I try what you say

Comment: That's what I was initially trying but it wouldn't work with the 0 being the value. It looks like (maybe for Windows) I have to use `obj->setProperty("flags", Qt::Window);`. Now it works as expected.

Comment: @slayer , It may be something else , because I try it in windows 10 with MSVC 2019 and Qt 5.15.2 , and worked.if  you want I can record it too

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum), it looks like `Qt::Widget` is set to `0x000000` and `Widgets of this type are child widgets if they have a parent, and **independent windows** if they have no parent.`